# How to create Minimal List of two Lists in R?

Tags: r, list, testing

I am trying to create a minimal list of two lists in R based on the thread [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/54964) but it does not cover the list of lists as a basic example. 
Wanted minimum data sample of the following structure where B length can be minimised but must be heterogeneous

```
List of 2
 $ :'data.frame':   541650 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ V1: num [1:541650] -0.21 -0.205 -0.225 -0.22 -0.21 -0.19 -0.205 -0.205 -0.205 -0.205 ...
  ..$ V2: num [1:541650] -0.245 -0.22 -0.2 -0.2 -0.195 -0.2 -0.19 -0.185 -0.18 -0.185 ...
 $ :'data.frame':   426098 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ V1: num [1:426098] -0.285 -0.285 -0.185 -0.285 -0.385 -0.305 -0.305 -0.125 -0.015 -0.285 ...
  ..$ V2: num [1:426098] -0.445 -0.6 -0.815 -0.665 -0.49 -0.68 -0.555 -0.755 -0.795 -0.405 ...
```

Doing `dput(files)`, you get too big example data. 
Doing `reproduce(files)`, the same case. 
I also tried `dput(head(files, 5))` but to one list and returns then only 5 digits. 
Pseudocode

- structure List A of two lists B(1,2) where the length of B(1,2) varies such that

  ```
  length(B(1)_i) = length(B(2)_i)
  ```
- minimise length of B(1,2) but keep heterogeneous length of subsequent Bs

Wanted output structure

```
List of 2
$ data.frame 11 obs. of 2 variables 
    $ V1: num [1:11] -0.21 -0.205 ...
    $ V2: num [1.11] -0.245 -0.22 ...
$ data.frame 7 obs. of 2 variables 
    $ V1: num [1:7] -0.285 -0.286 ...
    $ V2: num [1.7] -0.445 -0.6 ...
```

R: 3.3.1
OS: Debian 8.5

Comment: Try `lst <- list(data.frame(V1 = rnorm(11), V2 = rnorm(11)), data.frame(V1 = rnorm(7), V2 = rnorm(7)))`  Or use a loop `lst1 <- lapply(c(11, 7), function(n) data.frame(V1 = rnorm(n), V2 = rnorm(n)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in a couple of ways.  Create the two `data.frame` and place it in a `list`

```
lst <- list(data.frame(V1 = rnorm(11), V2 = rnorm(11)), 
             data.frame(V1 = rnorm(7), V2 = rnorm(7)))
```

Or if there are many `data.frame`s to be create, use a loop

```
lst1 <- lapply(c(11, 7), function(n) data.frame(V1 = rnorm(n), 
                               V2 = rnorm(n)))
```

Comment: alternatively, `split(data.frame(V1 = rnorm(18), V2 = rnorm(18)), 1:18 < 7)`